# How can I make notifications in Windows 10 not interfere with full screen games?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, notifications

Many full screen games ( specifically League of Legends in my case ) will only run on the primary monitor. Unfortunately, Windows 10 notifications also seem to only appear on the primary monitor, even if the "primary" taskbar has been relocated to a secondary monitor.

When those games are running in "fullscreen borderless", Windows 10 notifications appear on top of the game -- which can be pretty detrimental to the game experience.

I know I can enable the "quiet hours" for notifications, which should suppress them entirely, but I would prefer to see them on another monitor. I've googled around quite a bit with no luck -- do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I assume it will always be on the primary monitor, and I can find no way to change it to secondary, but someone else might find a way to tweak notifications to pop under instead of pop over, in the registry.